# Topological Dimension of Quotient Space

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups, topological-groups, quotient-spaces, dimension-theory-analysis

For a topological space $\mathcal X$ and a quotient space $\mathcal Y$ of $\mathcal X$, [Wikipedia's page on quotient spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)) says that the topological dimension of $\mathcal Y$ can be more than that of $\mathcal X$, for instance in the case of space-filling curves.

Are there conditions under which $\mathcal Y$ is known to be of finite topological dimension, or where $\mathrm{dim} Y <= \mathrm{dim} X$? I am particularly interested in the case when $\mathcal Y = \mathcal X / G$ is the quotient by a group $G$, though any leads would be nice. For motivation, I am interested in when quotient spaces can be embedded into Euclidean space, and it is known that many spaces with finite dimension can be embedded into Euclidean space.

Comment: Well, for instance if the action of $G$ is properly discontinuous, or $G$ is a Lie group acting properly. Is this what you are interested in?

Comment: The easy case is when $G$ is finite. In general the relationship between $\dim X$ and $\dim Y$ when there is a continuous closed/open surjection $f\colon X\to Y$ is complicated and depends on $\dim f=\sup_{y\in Y}\dim f^{-1}(y)$. Chapter 9.2 of Pears *Dimension Theory of General Spaces* contains a lot of informations about results of this kind

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti thanks for the reference, this is really useful and does give quite a few sufficient conditions.